# Send text to an Arduino LCD display with C#

Tags: c#, arduino

So, I am trying to send a simple text through my c# application to an arduino with an LCD display, but I have no idea I can I do that. Do you have something to help me?

Comment: First result when you google the problem: http://stigern.net/blog/tutorial-c-communicating-with-arduino-over-serial/

Comment: That is not really what I am looking for..I want to send a text and display it into the lcd arduino display box @JayGould

Comment: Again, first result when searching. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wN5DPOGD9g Did you do any research into this before asking on SO?

Comment: But there is no help on it. Its just showing the final product @JayGould

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stage 1: "I have no idea I can do that"

response 1: http://stigern.net/blog/tutorial-c-communicating-with-arduino-over-serial/#codesyntax_1

stage 2: "That is not really what I am looking for..I want to send a text and display it"

At least you should admit that you now got an idea how a c# program could talk to an Arduino in general.

Using a text instead of transmitting a binary value shouldn't be too hard, or is that your issue?

Text instead of binary has the advantage, that both sides are more independent.
Instead of a c# application, you might use Arduino SerialMonitor to send some text. Thus you can concentrate on the Arduino side first.

**Another hint:** use NewLine '\n' as a control character:
Can't be displayed on the LCD anyway, and SerialMonitor can be configured to append it automatically when you submit a line: a natural choice for an end-of-message marker.

Comment: I already know how to communicate with an arduino using serial port. And I know how to send and receive data, but in a simple way like "0" and "1" to turn on and turn of led's.

Comment: Usually, you won't get a solution here. Show your attempt and explain where (optimally "why") you're stuck.
a) Send more than 1 char ? b) Receive more than 1 char ? c) put received chars to an LCD ?